# Angular doesn't call resolve in my route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in Angular, and I'm trying to understand the basic
My Project is like Mean.

My router.js

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {});
});
```

my Angularfile.js

```
var app = angular.module('ibApp', ['ngRoute','ui.router']);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '/',
            resolve: {
                foo: [function () {
                    console.log('inside')
                }]
            }
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }]);



app.controller("MyCtrl",['$scope',function($scope) {
    console.log("here!");
}]);
```

my index.html

```
 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
```

But when I get the / (index) route, I haven't console.log('inside'), but I have only console.log("here");

I tried also `http://localhost:3000/#/`, but my problem persist.

Comment: remove [ ] from the function.

Comment: in resolve? I tried, but I have the same problem

Comment: resolve is returning the function to your controller, not the result of the function, and since the function isn't named, you don't have any way to execute the function in the controller.  add `()` to ensure the function executes.

Comment: Alert() doesn't work neither?

Comment: @Claies am I missing something? resolve does run the function, see [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider): "if function, then it is injected and the return value is treated as the dependency"

Comment: - claises , thanks but I don't understand.
- gr3g it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think you can use `ngRoute` with `ui-router`, use one or the other bu not both together

Comment: @Michelem, I removed ngRoute, but same error

Comment: @doldt I explained a bit in my answer; essentially, the function isn't executed in this case, because the dependency isn't the function, it's an array which holds the function as element 0.

Comment: @Claies yes indeed, I too meant if it *were* a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Resolve provider is not executing the function in your case.  The function itself is being returned as the dependency object, because the function is never invoked.  If the function is invoked, the return value of the function is treated as the dependency.

try:

```
resolve: {
    foo: [function () {
            console.log('inside')
          }()]
    }
```

note the `()` at the end of the function declaration to invoke the function.

You can also return the function with a name, and invoke the function inside the controller.

Note that the reason this is occurring is because `foo` is not being provided the function as the resolve object (which would implicitly execute the function and assign the result to `foo`), rather `foo` is declared as an array, and the function is simply `foo[0]`.  You could *also* invoke the function as `foo[0]` in the controller.

Based on your comments, you are trying to execute a service function and return the result.  In this case, you should ensure the service is available to the module, and then simply invoke it.  It is not necessary to try to inject the service into your resolve function the way you might with a controller declaration.

i.e. instead of doing :

```
resolve: { 
    postPromise: ['users', function (users) {
        console.dir('here '+users);
        return users.getAll();
    }]
```

you can do:

```
app.config([
'$interpolateProvider',
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
'users',
function ($interpolateProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, users) {
...

resolve: { 
    allTheUsers: function (users) {
        console.dir('here '+users);
        return users.getAll();
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FOgVgz5kvfuzPAAgtsVC?p=preview

Comment: My problem is little bit complicated. I want get the data in resolve, after call my service with $http. You can find the code here http://pastebin.com/PDN9Arkd. my resolve doesn't call my service, and inside my controller, I don't have my data.

Comment: again, you are returning `postPromise` as an array, with `'users'` as `postPromise[0]`, and your function as `postPromise[1]`.  this isn't going to invoke the function, nor is it going to supply `users` as a parameter for the function (it's not a dependency injection array).

Comment: @monkeyUser I updated my answer with what I think you are probably trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, again. I'm trying your code , but I don't see `'here'+user`

Comment: I updated the function to show where to inject `users`.

Comment: thanks, but I received this error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
and, I followed this tutorial https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/#wiring-everything-up, and he does exactly what I Want do

Comment: hmm, I'll dig into this a bit more later today if I get an opportunity; I'm sorry you are having so much trouble here.  One other thing I noticed (which may or may not be an issue):  in your question, your scripts show angular 1.3.10 but angular-route 1.4.1.  Odd things can happen when these two scripts are not matching versions.